# how to troubleshoot proxy issues on Mavericks

Tags: networking, proxy

For a few days i've been working on my own gear (mabook pro retina, latest mavericks) while plugged on corporate network.

This network, of course (why make it simple when you can complicate right?), has a TMG proxy. I did set the proxy on my configurations and everything, and i know it is correct because it works fine, until it does not. Yes, like that... i'm very happy and joyful navigating the web, reading my news, accessing msdn, youtube, you name it, and then suddenly I can only get internal access... the internet just vanishes.

The funny thing is that safari just goes blank as if the proxy kept saying "hang in there for a couple more seconds"... i dont get 407 (proxy authentication) or any other error... Can anyone help me troubleshoot this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with Sarafi itself... Chrome for MAC works just fine... fine, not perfect, because every once in a while it asks for my proxy authentication again... which is annoying...